# how to set different font styles to text views

Tags: android

I need complete details regarding setting the fonts of various styles and in which folders we have to mention the styles and everything.

like ProximoNova-Semibold.otf,ProximoNova-Regular.otf

Comment: Just double ckick the OTF file. Click install.

Answer (score 0):

Download the required font from the internet, and then place it in assets/fonts folder.

You can access it in your java code through Typeface class.

```
TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font name.ttf");
tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```

Comment: Did you download the correct ttf file?
Did you replace "name.ttf" in the above code snippet with the actual name of your file?

Comment: txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Card_label);
   Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto/ProximoNova-Regular.otf");
  txt1.setTypeface(custom_font);*/

Comment: Try to get the ttf version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library with custom options available in library. Otherwise use includeMe's code.